# Adding to GWT RootPanel or just setting the default view?

Tags: java, gwt, widget, gwt-places, gwt-activities

I have the following GWT classes:

```
public class MyDefaultView extends Composite {
    // Uses UiBinder and just contains all the widgets for this view.
}

public class MyDefaultActivity extends AbstractActivity {
    @Inject
    private MyDefaultView myDefView;

    @Override
    public void start(AcceptsOneWidget panel, EventBus eventBus) {
        panel.setWidget(myDefView);
    }
}

public class MyActivityMapper implements ActivityMapper {
    @Override
    public Activity getActivity(Place place) {
        if(place instanceof MyDefaultPlace)
            return new MyDefaultActivity();
        else
            return null;
    }
}

public class MyAppModule implements EntryPoint {
    @Override
    public void onModuleLoad() {
        // Lots of initialization and wiring...

        // Why do I need this?!?
        MyDefaultView myDefaultView = GWT.create(MyDefaultView.class);
        RootPanel.add(myDefaultView);

        Place myDefaultPlace = GWT.create(MyDefaultPlace.class);

        PlaceHistoryHandler historyHandler = getHistoryHandler();
        historyHandler.register(myPlaceController, myEventBus, myDefaultPlace);
        historyHandler.handleCurrentHistory();
    }
}
```

1. Why do I need to add `MyDefaultView` to `RootPanel`, if I'm just going to call `PlaceHistoryHandler#handleCurrentHistory()` and display `MyDefaultView` when the module loads?
2. If I shouldn't be adding `MyDefaultView` directly to `RootPanel`, then what should I be adding?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You don't need to add `MyDefaultView`, but you need to a panel that implements `AcceptsOneWidget` and set that panel on the activity manager. This will take care of having your views made visible.

2) In most applications you have a part of the application that is always visible. For example a bar at the top showing among other things the user name. This kind panel needs to be added to the root panel. In that panel on the position where your views should be visible  a widget/panel that implements `AcceptsOneWidget` should be used. This widget should be set as display in your activityManager, via `setDisplay`. That widget will be passed to the `start` method in your activity. Here is how the code to use with the ActivityManager and RootPanel could look like:

```
final ActivityManager activityManager = new ActivityManager(myActivityMapper, eventBus);

activityManager.setDisplay(rootView.getViewPanel());
Rootpanel.add(rootView);
```